# Файл httpd.core

Tags: php, apache

Недавно в нескольких папках сайта на php (маленький интернет-магазин) появился файл `httpd.core` (180 Mb). Хотелось бы узнать, для чего этот файл нужен и почему он появился.

Comment: а что про него говорит программа file? `file путь/к/httpd.core`

Comment: имеете ввиду функцию php file() ?

Comment: нет, программу [file](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28Unix%29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> В современных Unix-подобных операционных системах, дамп памяти
>   сохраняется в виде файла который обычно называется core или
>   core.<номер процесса>; его формат такой же, как формат исполняемых
>   файлов этой ОС (ELF в Linux и современных Unix, a.out в традиционных
>   Unix-системах, Mach-O в Mac OS X). Для анализа core-файла используется
>   отладчик (например gdb) или инструмент objdump.

[wikipedia©](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8)

Судя по имени `httpd.core`, предположительно, падал `Apache`.

От сюда вопросы:
1. Что за среда?
2. Были ли падения?

Comment: веб сервер nginx/1.6.2. падения были, сайт стоит у хостера. спасибо за ответ. обращусь в техподдержку хостера.